# Why doesn't my .htaccess setup work with $_GET?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+) display.php?id=$1
```

However, in display.php when I try to access the value for `$_GET['id']`, PHP says there is no value.

Currently `display.php?id=1` works fine but `display/1` doesn't work. I have also tried to see if `display/id=1` or `display.php/1` work, but none do.

My `display.php` file is also in a folder called 'resources' so it's address is `domain.com/resources/display.php`, maybe that can help.

Comment: How are you trying to get the value?

Comment: $_GET['id'] The URL is something like domain.com/resources/display.php?id=1

Comment: What do you mean by " `display/1` doesn't work" ? Do you get a 404 not found error when you go to `example.com/display/1` ?

Comment: Yes, it says page not found.